# Transferring points to another user for answering based on a comment

Tags: feature-request

Would it make sense to have a feature where User-A can donate points to User-B?

I've seen situations where User-B posts a valid answer in a short comment, and then User-A comes along and posts a full answer based on User-B's comments. (In most cases, User-A is nice enough to thank and cite User-B in their answer.)

If I were User-A, I'd like to go a step further and transfer a fraction of the points earned from that answer to User-B!

(Related post: [Transferring reputation points between accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78355/transferring-reputation-points-between-accounts) but I think the situation I described is a bit different.)

(Or maybe, the first answer here [Transfer/Award Reputation between users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23841/transfer-award-reputation-between-users) is the way to go!)

Comment: I completely agree!  [My highest-rated SO answer was "stolen" from a comment!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034048/xcode-linker-error-file-too-small-for-architecture-x86-64/29952569#29952569)

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree (answer stolen from @PeterK. comment:).

A very good option is to consider that a "perfect answering" comment is a philanthropic action. The commenter could have answered instead for his benefit.

Philanthropy should draw attention to the  commenter, and that **could** incite the OP and the valid answer providers (inspired by the comment) to pay some attention to  his/her other answers, and vote them up.